# Issue with event listener for displaying button set in a simple text editor

Tags: javascript, event-listener, text-editor

I'm trying to code a very simple text editor. The only feature this editor have is, when the user selects a part of the text, to display a small button set under the selected text. (Button set will consist of options like "bold", "italic", and "underlined"). But I can't find the true event listener to that. My code is here, without any button set, just checking if it works, but in the first click somewhere else to remove the selection, still 'console.log(selection.toString(),"active")' line is executed.

My code;

```
el.addEventListener('mouseup',() => {
    const selection = window.getSelection()
    if(selection.toString().length > 0) console.log(selection.toString(),"active")
    else console.log("false")
  })
```

Note: Editor is a contenteditable div, so I can't use 'select' event.

Comment: I think you want the [select event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select_event).

Comment: @mykaf I use a contenteditable div, select event works with only inputs

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether the selection range is collapsed or not. If the range is collapsed, it means that the user has clicked outside the selected text, and you can ignore the event. Here's an updated version of your code that incorporates this check:

```
el.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (!selection.isCollapsed && selection.toString().length > 0) {
    console.log(selection.toString(), "active");
  } else {
    console.log("false");
  }
});
```

By adding !selection.isCollapsed to the condition, the code will only log the selected text as "active" when the selection is not collapsed (i.e., when there is a range of selected text). When the selection is collapsed, indicating that the user clicked outside the selected text, it will log "false" instead.

With this modification, the 'mouseup' event will only trigger the desired behavior when there is an actual selection made by the user.

Comment: It still does the same thing, if I don't click twice at least, it contunes to execute the command 'console.log(selection.toString(), "active");'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close with the `mouseup` event, since you will trigger that event when you perform a selection. However, the event might occur too fast / not often enough and then `window.getSelection()` will still show length>0 even though nothing was selected.

I don't know an alternative regarding events you could use. But as a possible solution, you could create your own listener by setting a `setInterval`. But then you do not have the mouse coordinates to move your 'palette' towards to. So to fix that, you register both:

- one just registers mouse events when the mouseup event has triggered
- one that 'listens' with a specific interval and shows/hides the palette

Here's an example:

```js
//  set body contentediitable=true. Can be any other div
document.body.contentEditable = true;

//  hook ito mouse up event
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
window.setInterval(selectionHandler, 500);

//  vars to store mouse coords
let mx, my;

//  offsets, can be dynamic based on width/height of palette
const [dx, dy] = [-75, 10];

//  get palette
const palette = document.querySelector('#palette');

//  handler for on mouse up, only store mouse coords from event
function mouseUp(event) {
  [mx, my] = [event.pageX, event.pageY];
}

//  handler on interval, if there is a selection, show palette and move to mouse coords
function selectionHandler() {
  //  hide it on trigger
  palette.style.opacity = 0;

  //  verify that something was selected
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.toString().length > 0) {
    //  show palette
    palette.style.opacity = 1;
    
    //  move palette to correct location with offset
    palette.style.left = (mx+dx) + 'px';
    palette.style.top = (my+dy) + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Courier;
  background-color: #55165e;
  color: #f9ceff;
}

#palette {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="palette">[B] [I] [S]</div>

if (true === true) {
<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log('It\'s really true!');
<br />
}
```

Alternatively to this solution, instead of using a setInterval, you can add a `setTimeout` after triggering the `mouseup` event, which should create a a stable solution as well.

Hope it helps!